# Validation not working on form in Modal using cTools in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, forms, chaos-tool-suite

I have a form which I am calling in popup modal using cTools, I added some validation rules in custom JavaScript file but those validations are not working and form is getting submitted, though validation on drupal level is working like suppose if I make the field required in form by adding #required it works fine but adding rule for required in jquery is not working. Can you explain why and provide a solution for this ?

```
$('#form_ID').validate({
                    //errorElement: 'span',
                    rules:{
                        first_name: {
                            required: true,
                            minlength: 3,
                            maxlength:30
                        },
                        last_name: {
                            required: true,
                            minlength: 3,
                            maxlength:30
                        },
                        select: {
                            required: true
                        },
                    },
                    messages:{
                        first_name: {
                            required: "Please enter a first name",
                            minlength: "Your name must consist of at least 3 characters",
                            maxlength: "Your name must consist of at least 30 characters"
                        },
                        last_name: {
                            required: "Please enter a last name",
                            minlength: "Your last name must consist of at least 3 characters",
                            maxlength: "Your last name must consist of at least 30 characters"
                        },
                        select: {
                            required: "Please confirm you have approval from your authorised account representative to use this account.",
                        },
                    }

                });
```

These validations are not working on js level.

Comment: For obvious reasons, we can’t guess why your custom js code doesn’t work, no. Please edit the question and provide a full description of the problem, including the relevant portions of code. If it’s just a plain JS/jQuery problem Stack Overflow is the right place to ask. If you identify a Drupal-specific problem please flag for reopening once you’ve made the edits. Many thanks

Comment: @Clive Do you have any working example of adding validation on js level in cTools modal form and form should not submit until all validations are true ?

Comment: I don’t, but we don’t provide or locate examples/tutorials here, just answer specific questions that are unique to Drupal. Your question may well be that, but we won’t know until you describe what the problem is in detail

Comment: Added code to explain what is not working.

Comment: Thanks, the edit clears up that this is a plain JS/jQuery issue (Drupal doesn’t use the jQuery validate plugin), so please use Stack Overflow for this one

Comment: How can we achieve this within Drupal if we want the same validation i.e on client side i.e. before submit the form ?